# Sencha upgrade to 2.1 removes all list styles

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

After i upgraded sencha touch from 2.0 to 2.1, all my list styles have gone for a toss. How do i get it back? Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean custom styling?

If you probably have to reconfigure your css with new selectors.
In the release notes of 2.1 (actually 2.1.0-b3) the new list component is added to 2.1 and it requires some css editing:

> Due to these changes, the DOM structure was altered for lists and you
>   may need to change some css selectors to add appropriate styling for
>   your lists. Typically you need to change the selector from
>   '.x-list-item' to '.x-list-item > .x-dock-vertical > .x-dock-body' for
>   any padding or margins you may have added.

More detail in: http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/alpha/2.2.0.52/release-notes.html